# R how to make assignments and reference a variable name converted from a string

Tags: r, cbind

My question is embedded in the code below.

I have created variable names from character strings, and I can assign values to those variable names (in this case, a list), but I can't do any simple operations on the lists unless I use the created variable names, which I do not want to do. How can I do simple operations with these lists, such as in the example, cbind?

```
id = c(96, 99)
namevector = paste("id.", per, sep = "")
assign(namevector[1],c(2,3))
assign(namevector[2],c(52,53))
cbind(id.96, id.99) # This is the desired answer. How do I get it, without using "id.96" or "id.99"?
#here are ideas that did not work 
cbind(namevector[1], namevector[2])
cbind(as.name(namevector[1]), as.name(namevector[2]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the objects in a `list` and then `cbind` the `list` elements to a single dataset with `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind, mget(namevector))
#      id.96 id.99
#[1,]     2    52
#[2,]     3    53
```

assuming `per` is `id`